# Highcharts - equal spacing between X-axis values having tickPositioner

Tags: highcharts

I am passing some values for the x-axis through the tickPositioner attribute. These values are not equally spaced from each other. My requirement is that I want these values to be equally spaced from one another even though they are not having equal difference from each other. Pls see my code below:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
     renderTo: 'container'
 },
 credits: {
     enabled: false
 },
 title: {
     text: 'Duration vs Productive Hours'
 },
 xAxis: [{
     allowDecimals: false,
     title: {
         text: 'Hours'
     },
     labels: {
         rotation: -90,
         align: 'right',
         style: {
             fontSize: '10px'
         }
     },
     tickPositioner: function () {
         var pos;
         tickPositions = [];
         tickStart = 100000;
         for (pos = tickStart; pos <= 1000000000; pos *= 10) {
             tickPositions.push(pos);
         }
         return tickPositions;
     }
 }],
 exporting: {
     width: 1024,
     filename: 'Duration_vs_Productive_Hours',
     buttons: {
         exportButton: {
             menuItems: [{
                 text: 'Export to PNG image',
                 onclick: function () {
                     this.exportChart();
                 }
             }, {
                 text: 'Export to JPEG image',
                 onclick: function () {
                     this.exportChart({
                         type: 'image/jpeg'
                     });
                 }
             }, {
                 text: 'Export to PDF file',
                 onclick: function () {
                     this.exportChart({
                         type: 'application/pdf'
                     });
                 }
             },
             null]
         }
     }
 },
 yAxis: [{
     min: 0,
     tickInterval: 10,
     max: 60,
     labels: {
         formatter: function () {
             return this.value;
         },
         style: {}
     },
     showEmpty: true,
     alternateGridColor: '#f7f7f7',
     gridLineColor: '#e7e7e7',
     allowDecimals: false,
     title: {
         text: 'Duration (Months)',
         style: {}
     }
 }],
 tooltip: {
     crosshairs: true,
     formatter: function () {
         if (this.series.type == 'line') {
             return '' + this.x;
         } else {
             return '' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
         }
     }
 },
 legend: {
     layout: 'horizontal',
     align: 'center',
     verticalAlign: 'bottom',
     backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
 },
 series: [{
     name: 'Other Projects',
     type: 'scatter',
     data: [
         [560000, 13],
         [185250, 11],
         [3625788, 23],
         [1648510, 21],
         [265000, 14],
         [13000000, 43],
         [28000000, 34],
         [1567000, 19],
         [1190000, 20],
         [21000000, 31],
         [7000000, 33],
         [3805200, 30],
         [17000000, 29],
         [1503267, 21],
         [11332332, 29],
         [1485067, 20],
         [5000000, 30],
         [5400000, 22],
         [13000000, 23],
         [3810000, 26],
         [810000, 18],
         [27528218, 26],
         [377319, 14],
         [840000, 22],
         [550000, 13],
         [2643142, 26],
         [412800, 13],
         [2500000, 22],
         [4510000, 19],
         [523116, 15],
         [17600000, 28],
         [2500000, 21],
         [21000000, 29],
         [3500000, 17],
         [620000, 15],
         [163000000, 46],
         [134000000, 41],
         [45000000, 39],
         [13677454, 31],
         [167000000, 52],
         [47000000, 33],
         [49000000, 38],
         [31000000, 38]
     ]
 }, {
     name: 'User Data',
     type: 'line',
     data: [
         [4050000, 0],
         [4050000, 60]
     ]
 }] });
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make the axis logarithmic. Try setting

```
xAxis:{
    type:"logarithmic"
```

And remove the. Tickpositioner.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type

If you do this, you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/TsaMA/ with the xAxis ticks equally spaced at 1M, 10M and 100M.

There are two xAxis settings which may: tickInterval and tickPixelInterval.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

If you set

```
tickInterval:1
```

You get 1M, 10M and 100M, which is the closest I can get to what you want.

tickPixelInterval is useful if you know the width of your chart. If your chart is 1000px wide you can set tickPixelInterval:250.

Comment: Hi SteveP, I don't want logarithmic as it is splitting my x-axis as 200K,400K,600K,etc. What I want is to give the x-axis values as 0.1M,1M,10M,100M and so on but with equal spacing between each ticks.Pls help.

Comment: 0.1,1,10,100 is logartihmic. Updated with jsfiddle example.

Comment: But there is a fixed width for the div that contains the highchart.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggest ? If so, what is wrong with it ?

Comment: Yes I tried what you suggested. It works when the width of the div is fixed at 600px. My div that contains the chart in the application should occupy the entire width of the screen. Then it goes like 200K, 400K, and so on.